# How to solve error 255 with Composer and Symfony

Tags: php, symfony, composer-php

I have a problem with Composer, when I run the `composer install` command, an error 255 appears.

Here are the tasks I have done to solve this:

- I updated Composer and the error is present in version 1 and 2
- `composer sync-recipes -v --force`
- Reinstalled synfony 5
- Updated the PC

I am running Ubuntu 20.04.

Error detail:

```
Don't forget to run npm install --force or yarn install --force to refresh your JavaScript dependencies!
Run composer recipes at any time to see the status of your Symfony recipes.

Executing script cache:clear [KO]
 [KO]
Script cache:clear returned with error code 255
!!  PHP Fatal error:  Declaration of Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ServiceLocator::has(string $id) must be compatible with Psr\Container\ContainerInterface::has($id) in /home/massi/Projets/projet-RH/vendor/symfony/dependency-injection/ServiceLocator.php on line 46
!!  Symfony\Component\ErrorHandler\Error\FatalError {#92
!!    -error: array:4 [
!!      "type" => 64
!!      "message" => "Declaration of Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ServiceLocator::has(string $id) must be compatible with Psr\Container\ContainerInterface::has($id)"
!!      "file" => "/home/massi/Projets/projet-RH/vendor/symfony/dependency-injection/ServiceLocator.php"
!!      "line" => 46
!!    ]
!!    #message: "Compile Error: Declaration of Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ServiceLocator::has(string $id) must be compatible with Psr\Container\ContainerInterface::has($id)"
!!    #code: 0
!!    #file: "./vendor/symfony/dependency-injection/ServiceLocator.php"
!!    #line: 46
!!  }
!!  
Script @auto-scripts was called via post-install-cmd
```

Comment: This does not look like a problem with Composer itself to me, but rather like a problem with the installed packages. Please share more details about them

Comment: Does https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/40870 help?

Comment: Error 255 on the command-line is just like error 500 on a web-page, it doesn't tell you much. The actual error you need to be looking at is the line beginning "PHP Fatal error" in that output.

Comment: Thanks Nico Haase it's work for me !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it's a probleme to a package recently updated

`composer require symfony/service-contracts:2.2.0`

:)

Comment: Just as a hint: it might be fine to simply **update** the given package instead of requiring it manually, especially if you set such a strict version constraint